# How to solve slowness of the dataChanged signal when adding a row to my QTreeView?

Tags: python, qt, qtreeview

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/22379130/21860235[the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22379130/21860235%5Bthe) post 8 years ago][1]

Hello, I would like to understand what is the `trolltech modelest` that he disabled in order to have a fast `datachanged.emit(QModelIndex(), QModelIndex())` signal. I don't have a lot of items in my `QTreeView`, so it shouldn't take 0,1 seconds each time this `signal` is emitted.

**Edit**

As I said in the comment section, when I remove this line : `self.model.dataChanged.connect(self.onDataChanged)` the program works as fast as excpected. This method is not big at all, I only use it to update data in my database (the model is built on this database).

```py
def onDataChanged(self) :
        item_id = self.currentIndex().siblingAtColumn(1).data()
        if self.currentIndex().isValid() :
            new_name = self.currentIndex().siblingAtColumn(0).data()
            con : Connexion() = Connexion()
            con.update("UPDATE cdc SET nom = :1 WHERE ID = :2",[new_name,item_id])
            self.update()
```

The object `con` comes from a class that connects to my database. I tested many queries and they all are fast to commit (less than 0,01 second) so I'm pretty sure the problem does not come from there. So I am wondering if implementing my own dataChanged function is altering Qt's functionnalities ?
Thanks for your answers

Comment: Why not ask with your own problem description and [mre]? Anyway, see [Model Test](https://wiki.qt.io/Model_Test).

Comment: I wonder if "modelest" is typo for "model test"?

Comment: @relent95 my program is getting bigger so it is hard to make an MRO with it. I am trying to make one currently, I'll edit my post when it is finished. Now, I tried many tests to see what slows my program and it appears that when I comment this : `self.model.dataChanged.connect(self.onDataChanged)`  , it goes way faster ! Check the edit of the post to see what this method does in my program

Comment: @relent95 I made an [MRO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but I can't see the problem as it works well. I am thinking if the issue comes from the fact that I have many `QTreeView` but I really don't now. Anyway, I created a `setData2` method to go around the problem. Is it a good idea to post it as an answer or should I just delete the post ?

Comment: I recommend to delete the question, because it does not help others in this state. You can read deleted questions from the Activity tab of your profile page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to not get the slowness of the signal `dataChanged` as it is directly linked with the `setData` method. I saw that connecting to my database is pretty long as I am doing standalones connections. So I created a `pool` with the following command : `self.pool = oracledb.create_pool(user= self.username, password= self.password, port= self.port, service_name= self.service, dsn= self.dsn, min = 2, max = 2, increment = 0)`. it allows the user to handle 2 connection at the same time. Also, I created another setData method that does not call the `dataChanged` signal when it is not necessary. It solved entirely my problem, here is the new method :

```py
def setData2(self, index: QModelIndex, value, role: int) -> bool:
        if role != Qt.EditRole:
            return False

        item: TreeItem = self.get_item(index)
        result: bool = item.set_data(index.column(), value)

        return result
```

Hope it solved your issue too !